# Tool to convert IBM WVR (DirectTalk) state table applications to pure vxml applications

Tags: websphere, ivr, vxml, voicexml

I am searching for a tool to convert IBM WVR 4.2 (DirectTalk) state table applications to pure voice xml application. I am thinking to port some of our state table applications out to a different voice xml platform.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A former employer went through a similar exercise.  I believe that IBM has a tool that can port DT state tables to VXML, but you'll likely have to engage a professional services agreement to get at it.

In reality, though, you should just flow out your application's narratives, and then rewrite it; State Tables and Prompts are a long way from a smoothly/elegantly designed VXML app.  For what it's worth, my former employer ditched their state table app and built from scratch, and they're much happier with what they've got.

If you're new to VXML, in general, there are some great tutorials over at [Voxeo](http://www.voxeo.com).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks IVR Avenger. Thanks for the link, I am not new to VXML, and been working on it years for now.. mainly on different platforms like Tellme and Nuance... thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to just call the state tables from the VXML Application.